# Best way to manage data a third party database and Firestore? Google Flutter

Tags: database, flutter, architecture, google-cloud-firestore, scalability

I'm working on a mobile app using Google Flutter that requires accessing a database through JSON requests and API's. Also the database isn't controlled by me so if I want additional features, I would have to pay (a significant amount of money to the database company).

Because accessing the database requires a  authentication token that only lasts for 1 hour, I'm thinking that everytime the user logs in or resumes the app, a cloud function is triggered to retrieve information from the third party database and copies it to a collection on Firestore. Then on the app, I would just access the collection from Firebase

I'm already using Firestore because I need it to push and access past push notifications. I have a cloud function that triggers a push notification when a new document is added to my "notifications" collection. Thay way I can access past notifications.

I've never done this before, are there other pros and cons I need to consider? 
How realistic is this approach?

Pros 
- Offline data persistence with Firestore
- Scalability (since there's a chance I'll be creating a webapp version in the future and different flavours of the app) I can reuse the cloud functions to sync back and forth with the third party database
- Ability to add future features at a lower cost (since the database company charges a like $130 an hour for development)
- Access to event triggers built into database
- Keep data to one database on the app, simplifies data streams

Cons
- Having to create seperate cloud functions to sync data across the two seperate databases
- Managing data?

Comment: If you're looking for opinions or a discussion, consider instead posting to a discussion board, such as Reddit.  https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/